# Get SKSpriteNode by name Swift 2, Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7, xcode7.2

I have around 120 `SKSpriteNode`s.

I have a matrix of the position of each sprite, in this matrix I store the name of the sprite.  I need to move a sprite to a new position.

How can I grab the following sprite by name:

```swift
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"BlueSquare")
sprite.name = "BlueSquare1"


// ... in another function
let newsprite = // ???? GET SKSpriteNode by name BlueSquare1????
```

How can I get a node by name and use the `SKAction.moveTo` function on that sprite?

Comment: `var yourSprite: SKSpriteNode = childNodeWithName("myNameSprite") as SKSpriteNode`, and then `yourSprite .runAction(SKAction….)`

Comment: ```var newsprite: SKSpriteNode = childNodeWithName("BlueSquare1") as! SKSpriteNode```. Don't forget to force downcast it with ```as!```

Answer (score 1):

**Calling a child node:**

If you have added your `sprite` to the `SKScene`, you will be able to call it later for use.

```swift
self.addChild(sprite)
```

If you want to call it in another method, you can use this:

```swift
let sprite = self.childNodeWithName("BlueSpuare1") as? SKSpriteNode
```

Note the use of casting `SKNode` to `SKSpriteNode`. You only need to do this when accessing properties unique to SKSpriteNode (i.e. `texture` or `colorBlendFactor`). This means that using the `SKAction.moveTo` method can be used on a `SKNode` and doesn't need to be casted.

---

**How to move the sprite:**

```swift
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene {
    func didMove(to: SKView) {
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"BlueSquare")
        sprite.name = "BlueSquare1"
        addChild(sprite)
        moveSquare("BlueSquare1") // Place this line anywhere you want it called
    }

    func moveSquare(_ square: String) {
        let moveTo: CGPoint = // to position
        let time: Double = // duration
        childNode(withName: square).moveTo(moveTo, duration: time)
    }
}
```

---

**Final Tips:**

- Note that calling the names of children is not recursive. Swift will not look into the names of grandchildren, etc.
- If 2 child nodes have the same name, Swift will find the first one inside the `children` array just as if you have wrote this instead: `self.children.first { $0.name == "BlueSquare1" }`
- If you do not give your node a name, it's default value is `nil`. That means it can never be called using the `childNode(withName: String)`. Instead, use `self.children.first { $0.name == nil }`.